# Oracle trigger to check if value was incremented

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Is it any way to check if a value was incremented in a update statement?

For example:

```
Table1 (id number,  Value number)

Insert into Table1(id, Value) values(1, 2);

UPDATE Table1
SET value = 3
WHERE id = 1
```

I need to know if the new value was incremented.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but hopefully the below will give you a start.

```
TRIGGER table1_update BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.value > :OLD.value then
      -- value has been incremented do what you need to do
   else if :NEW.value < :OLD.value then
      -- value has been decremented do what you need to do
   else
      -- value must be the same do whatever you need to do
   end if;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `returning .. into ..` structure to see the new incremented value as in the below block :

```
SQL> create table Table1( id number, value number );

Table created

SQL> insert into Table1(id, Value) values(1, 2);

1 row inserted

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> 
SQL> declare
  2   new_value Table1.value%type;
  3  begin
  4   update Table1
  5      set value = 3
  6    where id = 1
  7    returning value into new_value;
  8   dbms_output.put_line(' New Value returned is '||new_value);
  9  end;
 10  /

 New Value returned is 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> commit;

Commit complete
```

Comment: This is a better solution than a trigger because our code can reference the value populated by the `returning into` directly, whereas a trigger can only populate a table or use something lame like `dbms_output`.

Comment: Thank you @BarbarosÖzhan. But I really do something when an increment is detected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a trigger is that it does not communicate with the executing  code. So a trigger is no good if we need our program to choose one or several different branches depending on the outcome of the UPDATE statement.

We can use `sql%found` (or `sql%notfound`) to test whether our DML statement touched any records.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET value = 3
WHERE id = 1;

if sql%found then 
    dbms_output.put_line('record updated');
else
    dbms_output.put_line('record NOT updated');
end if;
```

If we have a statement which might affect more than one record we can use `sql%count` to get the number of affected records.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET value = 3
WHERE id > 123;

dbms_output.put_line('No of records updated = ' || sql%count);
```

If you want to get the updated value then use the `returning into` clause:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET value = value + 3
WHERE id = 1
returning value into l_value;

dbms_output.put_line('updated value = ' || l_value);
```